# Tratar req.files como null

Tags: node.js, express.js, mongoose, blog

Boa noite.
Estou começando agora com estudos em desenvolvimento web e gostaria de saber como tratar o seguinte:
O que desenvolvi foi um blog, e na área de criação de posts, existe um formulário para que se digitem:
Autor, Título do post, Descrição e Conteúdo.
Abaixo disto, existe um botão para fazer upload de uma imagem, que será usada como capa da postagem.
Entretanto, gostaria de permitir que a criação do post pudesse ser feito sem o envio da imagem.
Mas ao preencher apenas os campos textuais e não selecionar uma imagem, tenho o seguinte retorno:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'imagem' of 'req.files' as it is null.
Aqui estão meus códigos:
storePost.js

```
const path = require('path')

const Post = require('../database/models/Post')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    const {
        imagem
    } = req.files

    imagem.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/posts', imagem.name), (error) => {
        Post.create({
            ...req.body,
            imagem: `/posts/${imagem.name}`
        }, (error, post) => {
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    })
    
}
```

index.js

```
const storePostController = require('./controllers/storePost');
app.post('/posts/store', auth, storePostController);
```

Comment: Este foi o tutorial que segui para desenvolver o blog:
https://vegibit.com/node-js-blog-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

Para fazer o fluxo desejado você deve modificar o seu código para tratar o caso de não fazer o upload da imagem.

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é verificar se a propriedade existe antes de utilizar o valor, segue um exemplo:

const path = require('path')

const Post = require('../database/models/Post')

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
   //quando o req.files estiver definido
   if (req.files) {
       const { imagem } = req.files

       imagem.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/posts', imagem.name), (error) => {
       Post.create({
            ...req.body,
            imagem: `/posts/${imagem.name}`
            }, (error, post) => {
            res.redirect('/');
            });
        })
   } else {   
       Post.create({...req.body, imagem: null }, (error, post) => {
            res.redirect('/');
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.
Funcionou bem aqui.